# Reduce Google Cloud Endpoints request response header size

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, http-headers, google-cloud-endpoints

I'm using a Google Cloud App Engine and Google Cloud Endpoints API for my backend for an Android app.This is all in Java. I passing Json through to the backend. When I call an API method in the Endpoints from the Android App, I get an HTTP response from the App Engine. To reduce the download data load on my App I've reduced the body of the response as much as I can, i've set it up so that most of the time the message in the body is just a 'success' message and a custom ID tag.

I'd now like to try and reduce the size of the response header if possible. I haven't been able to figure this out or find much information about this online, could anyone help with this? I'm not even sure this is possible.

The properties in the response header seem to be set as defaults in the backend, I can't see where this is being done to try and modify it or remove some of them (assuming some of them are not absolutely necessary for the response to be delivered properly). The size of the header in each response is 500 bytes.My app is sending many small messages as the users will often be making small updates to data which needs to be pushed out and so 500 bytes for each response quickly adds up. This is especially a problem as most of my users will be away from wifi and will have somewhat low data plans on their phone.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the Endpoints frameworks simply aren't made for this kind of optimization. Are you sure it is 500 bytes after gzip compression? How certain are you that this optimization is necessary?

Comment: I'm using Charles proxy to monitor the HTTP traffic into the device. It tells me the compression of the response is minus 131.6% i.e. the size increased after compression. It tells me the size of the response header is 500 bytes. I wasn't 100% sure if that 500 bytes is before or after compression, but i assumed it would be at least that because if its 500bytes after decompression it'll be more than 1kb when compressed. I might just have to live with it for now and rethink how communication with the backend works later, thanks for your help! saves me wasting any more time going down this route